# Spatial Resolution Reprojection - rom Angular to Rectangular Values with GDAL?

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, resolution

I have an image in a [WGS 84 / No Defs](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/) projection. I can get it spatial resolutions in angular units for X axis and Y axis through geotransform parameters.

If I would reproject this image into [WGS 84 / World Mercator](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-world-mercator/), then geotransform parameters will become *reprojected* too, and I will be able to get new spatial resolution for my image in meters

How can I *reproject* those resolutions without image reprojection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [GDALAutoCreateWarpedVRT](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarper_8h.html#ab5a8723d68786e7554f1ad4c0a6fa8d3) function. This function creates a virtual raster dataset that represents the projected version of your raster. If you use this function, then you can read the properties of your image in the new coordinate system from the virtual raster's geotransform parameters.

Comment: Thank you for pointing into right direction! I decided to go with `GDALCreateReprojectionTransformer` and `GDALSuggestedWarpOutput`. Its such a shame, that I could not see this solution.